# How to generate a random number within a certain range using GMP

Tags: c++, random, gmp

I have tried to do this as follows:

```
int main(){
  mpz_t v;
  mpf_class u,w,x[3][200];     

  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
   for(j=0;j<3;j++){
     mpz_random(v,1000000);
     mpf_div_ui(w.get_mpf_t(),v,1000000);
     mpf_div(u.get_mpf_t(),1,2);
     mpf_sub(w.get_mpf_t(),w.get_mpf_t(),u);
     mpf_mul(x[i][j].get_mpf_t(),w.get_mpf_t(),2);
   }
  }
}
```

But the use of integers and floats together doesn't work. Basically tried assigning random integer, dividing by the max the integer could be giving a number (not necessarily integer) between 0 and 1. Minus a half and multiply by 2 gives a random number between -1 and 1 which is what I want, but like I said this causes issues due to types.

Comment: What "issues due to types" are you talking about precisely? You may want to consider using `mpf_urandomb()`. It might be simpler to multiply by 2 first, and then subtract 1.

Comment: @user315052 Sorry what I meant was that I get errors saying "invalid conversion from int to const..." meaning due to v being an integer, it can't be used in mpf functions.

Comment: @user315052 I have looked at the mpf_urandomb() function and it seems like what I want, except I have no idea what the "state" means,could someone please explain that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the intention of your program correctly, this should be more or less what you are after.

```
int main(){
  gmp_randstate_t state;
  mpf_class v, w, x[3][200];

  gmp_randinit_mt(state);
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<200;j++){
     mpf_urandomb(v.get_mpf_t(), state, 4);
     mpf_urandomb(w.get_mpf_t(), state, 256);
     if (v < .5) w *= -1;
     x[i][j] = w;
   }
  }
}
```

The `state` variable is used to inform the random number routine what algorithm you wish to use for your random number generator. In the code above, I have initialized it to use the Mersenne Twister algorithm.

You did not properly declare your `i` and `j` indices.

The first call to `mpf_urandomb()` gets a 4 bit random value between 0 and 1. It is used to decide if the next number should be negative or not.

The second call to `mpf_urandomb()` gets a 256 bit random value between 0 and 1. If the previous number was less than `.5`, then the value is negated.

This value is assigned to `x[i][j]`.

Comment: Why have you chosen those precisions may I ask?

Comment: You don't need a big precision just to make the decision of negative or not. The large precision I just made up. Use whatever makes sense for you.